# Is this question about studying techniques on topic here?

Tags: discussion

I'm a moderator on Medical Sciences.SE and I encountered a question today that is off topic for our site, but I believe it would be on topic here. However, I notice a lot of "how to study" questions here have been closed, so I want to be sure before migrating it.

Would [this question](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/26269/studying-anatomy) be considered on topic here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks for asking. I would **not** recommend migrating it, as I cannot think of any formulation that would bring it firmly on-topic:

- "How to study efficiently" is far too broad to be answerable, and there is little we could add to the mountain of advice that already exists online.
- "What are good study strategies for anatomy?" is a little better, but it's not clear (to me, at least) why studying anatomy would have different considerations than any other subject.
- "How to remember veins and arteries" could conceivably generate good answers (e.g., mnemonic devices), but is too subject-specific for this stack.

Glancing at our archives, the well-received "how to study" questions are all asking about how to mitigate some particular, well-defined impediment (e.g., anxiety, insufficient background for the class, or bizarrely-behaving instructors).

Comment: Okay, thanks. Your answer doesn't surprise me in the least so glad I asked first.